# Python 3 UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm implementing this [notebook](https://github.com/fastai/courses/blob/master/deeplearning1/nbs/lesson5.ipynb) on Windows with Python 3.5.3 and got the follow error on load_vectors() call. I've tried different solutions posted but none worked.

```
<ipython-input-86-dd4c123b0494> in load_vectors(loc)
      1 def load_vectors(loc):
      2     return (load_array(loc+'.dat'),
----> 3         pickle.load(open(loc+'_words.pkl','rb')),
      4         pickle.load(open(loc+'_idx.pkl','rb')))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should probably give encoding for `pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')`, but please make sure all the characters in your file will follow the encoding.

By default, your pickle code is trying to decode the file with 'ASCII' which fails. Instead you can explicitly tell which one to use. See this from [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load).

If latin1 doesn't solve, try with `encoding='bytes'` and then decode all the keys and values later on.

Comment: i am facing this issue when use csv. did you know how to fix it?

Comment: @radityagumay You could try encoding option while reading. How are you reading the file, and what's in the file?

Comment: just trying to write a csv file. and file looks like this https://paste.ofcode.org/CZk4aHSjvTwFfMU28JeRXk

Answer (score 13):

I solved this issue by copying and pasting the entire csv file into text and reading it with:

```
with open(self.path + "/review_collection.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    read = f.read().splitlines()
    for row in read:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as well. I realized that I copy and pasted text from a file that had left and right double-quotes (curly quotes). Once I changed it to the standard straight double-quotes (") the issue was fixed!

See this link for the difference between the quotes: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html