# Python 3 pickle load from Python 2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle

I have a pickle file that was created (I don't know how exactly) in python 2.  It is intended to be loaded by the following python 2 lines, which when used in python 3 (unsurprisingly) do not work:

```
with open('filename','r') as f:
    foo, bar = pickle.load(f)
```

Result:

> 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1219: ordinal not in range(128)

Manual inspection of the file indicates it is utf-8 encoded, therefore:

```
with open('filename','r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    foo, bar = pickle.load(f)
```

Result:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

With binary encoding:

```
with open('filename','rb', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    foo, bar = pickle.load(f)
```

Result:

> ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument

Without binary encoding:

```
with open('filename','rb') as f:
    foo, bar = pickle.load(f)
```

Result:

> UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '
>   '.

Is this pickle file just broken?  If not, how can I pry this thing open in python 3?  (I have browsed the extensive collection of related questions and not found anything that works yet.)

Finally, note that the original

> import cPickle as pickle

has been replaced with

> import _pickle as pickle

Comment: The first three errors are just the result of opening the file incorrectly. Only the `invalid load key, ' '` error is relevant. I don't know what might be causing that though. About your last few paragraphs, it should no longer be necessary to deal with any module other than `pickle` these days. It will load accelerated versions from `_pickle` automatically, if they're available. So just do `import pickle`!

Answer (score 3):

The loading of python2 pickles in python3 (version 3.7.2 in this example) can be helped using the *fix_imports* parameter in the pickle.load function, but in my case it also worked without setting that parameter to True.

I was attempting to load a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix contained in pickle generated using Python2.

When inspecting the file format using the UNIX command *file* it says:

```
>file -bi python2_generated.pckl
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

I could load the pickle in Python3 using the following code:

```
with open("python2_generated.pckl", "rb") as fd:
    bh01 = pickle.load(fd, fix_imports=True, encoding="latin1")
```

> Note that the loading was successful with and without setting fix_imports to True
>   As for the "latin1" encoding, the Python3 documentation (version 3.7.2) for the [pickle.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) function says:
>   Using encoding='latin1' is required for unpickling NumPy arrays and instances of datetime, date and time pickled by Python 2

Although this is specifically for scipy matrixes (or Numpy arrays), and since Novak is not clarifing what his pickle file contained,
I hope this could of help to other users :)

Comment: using `fix_imports=True` saved my day!

Comment: Happy to hear it helped...did not make any difference for though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Two errors were conflating each other.

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412959/pickle-dependency-failure):  By the time the .p file reached me, it had almost certainly been corrupted in transit, likely by FTP-ing (or similar) in ASCII rather than binary mode.  I was able to get my hands on a properly transmitted copy, which allowed me to discover...

[Second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46046966/1092746):  Whatever the file might have implied on the inside, the proper encoding was 'latin1' not 'utf-8'.

So in a sense, yes, the file *was* broken, and even after that I was doing it wrong.  I leave this here as a reminder to whoever eventually has the next bizarre pickle/python2/python3 issue that there can be multiple things gone wrong, and they have to be solved in the correct orderr.